# Which file system copes 'better' with bad ejects of external USB HDDs?

Tags: linux, filesystems, usb-drive, external-hdd, removable-storage

Is there a disk format that copes well (or better than others) when end users physically disconnect USB-attached external drives without safely ejecting then?

I have [XFS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XFS), [ext4](https://opensource.com/article/18/4/ext4-filesystem), [btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page), [exfat](https://eastmanreference.com/how-to-enable-exfat-support-on-linux), and [NTFS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164728/should-i-choose-exfat-or-ntfs-for-a-shared-partition-in-a-dual-boot-system) ([more](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-mount-partition-with-ntfs-file-system-and-read-write-access)) formats to choose from.

The disks don't have any data being written to them during the ejection, I just can't automate a clean eject for boring reasons I won't go into.

Comment: Apologies, I should have stated that these are USB external mechanical drives.

Comment: When you have new data or overlooked data which becomes relevant, please click [edit] and add it to the original question, as you will see I did above. You're on the scene and have the system in hand, all we can do is probe by asking questions, so your responses are most important and therefore should enhance the Question. The weblinks added above are very relevant to read.